# how can I set a dataset or datatable row to a value taken from a gridview textbox entry?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have the following code:

```js
  protected void GridView4_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CommandName == "UpdateGCommand")
        {
            if (IsPostBack)
            {
                DataSet EditT = new DataSet();
                DataSet ValidT = new DataSet();
                DataRow row;
                if (Session["Edit"] != null)
                {
                    EditT = (DataSet)Session["Edit"];
                }
                if (Session["Valid"] != null)
                {
                    ValidT = (DataSet)Session["Valid"];
                }

                DataTable dtEdit = EditT.Tables[0];
                DataTable dtValid = ValidT.Tables[0];



                GridViewRow gvr = (GridViewRow)(((LinkButton)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer);
                int RowIndex = gvr.RowIndex;
                row = dtEdit.Rows[RowIndex];
                //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                // Must be able to update the EditT or dtEdit with value from Gridview4 textboxes here
                //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                dtValid.Rows.Add(row.ItemArray);
                dtEdit.Rows[RowIndex].Delete();
                GridView4.DataSource = EditT;
                GridView5.DataSource = ValidT;
                GridView4.DataBind();
                GridView5.DataBind();
            }
            
        }
    }
```

And the following asp:

```html
<asp:GridView ID="GridView4" runat="server" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" 
            GridLines="None" OnRowCommand="GridView4_RowCommand" 
            OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView4_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
            <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
            <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:LinkButton OnClick="UpdateRow_Click" 
                        ID="LinkButton1" 
                        runat="server" 
                        CausesValidation="false" 
                        CommandName="UpdateGCommand" 
                        Text="Update">
                    </asp:LinkButton>                    
                </ItemTemplate>     
            </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox 
                        ID="textBox1" 
                        runat="server" 
                        Text='<%#Eval("Name")%>'>
                    </asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvName" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Name is a required field" 
                            ControlToValidate="textBox1" Text="*" ForeColor="Red">
                    </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                </ItemTemplate>
           </asp:TemplateField>
           <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Email">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox 
                        ID="textBox2" 
                        runat="server" 
                        Text='<%#Eval("Email")%>'>
                    </asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvEmail" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Email is a required field" 
                            ControlToValidate="textBox2" Text="*" ForeColor="Red">
                    </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                </ItemTemplate>
           </asp:TemplateField>
           <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Mobile">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox 
                        ID="textBox3" 
                        runat="server" 
                        Text='<%#Eval("Mobile")%>'>
                    </asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvMobile" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Mobile is a required field" 
                            ControlToValidate="textBox3" Text="*" ForeColor="Red">
                    </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>


        </Columns>
            <FooterStyle BackColor="#990000" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <HeaderStyle BackColor="#990000" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <PagerStyle BackColor="#FFCC66" ForeColor="#333333" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            <RowStyle BackColor="#FFFBD6" ForeColor="#333333" />
            <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#FFCC66" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="Navy" />
            <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#FDF5AC" />
            <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#4D0000" />
            <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#FCF6C0" />
            <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#820000" />
        </asp:GridView>
```

Here is what's happening:
Starting point
[image: Starting point]

Editing the Email in Row 2 to fit Email specifications

[image: Editing the Email in Row 2 to fit Email specifications]

After hitting the Update link button in Row 2

[image: After hitting the Update link button in Row 2]

As you can see I am not able to send the correct Value from the edit box as I don't know what code to use for it. Please help

Comment: Show you gridview .asp code :)

Comment: sorry forgot to add it lol

Comment: I'm not sure if I should mention that the data was uploaded from an Excel file and if the code for that is required to help get an answer

Comment: I don't think so , i'll take a look and try something, gl !

Comment: Thank you I really appreciate it! been part of stackoverflow for only 3 days now and I must say it is a great community to be in!

Comment: You're welcome, hope my answer give you some help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code. May be this is  what you need.

```js
 string txtName = ((TextBox) GridView4.Rows[RowIndex].FindControl("textBox1")).Text;
 string txtEmail = ((TextBox) GridView4.Rows[RowIndex].FindControl("textBox2")).Text;
 string txtMobile = ((TextBox) GridView4.Rows[RowIndex].FindControl("textBox3")).Text;

 if (txtName != null) {
   EditT.Tables[0].Rows[RowIndex]["Name"] = txtName;
 }


 if (txtEmail != null) {
   EditT.Tables[0].Rows[RowIndex]["Email"] = txtEmail;
 }

 if (txtMobile != null) {
   EditT.Tables[0].Rows[RowIndex]["Mobile"] = txtMobile;
 }
```

Do the same for other textboxes if it is useful. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your code can work, you only need to update your onrow_command method.

In this method you can get the edited row and all it's textbox value, then use it like you want. ( add a new line in your validated datatable for example )

```
protected void GridView4_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CommandName == "UpdateGCommand")
        {
            if (IsPostBack)
            {




                GridViewRow gvr = (GridViewRow)(((LinkButton)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer);
                int RowIndex = gvr.RowIndex;
                GridViewRow row = GridView4.Rows[RowIndex];

                //Actual edited values for this row

                //Name
                string name = ((TextBox)row.FindControl("textBox1")).Text.ToString();

                //Mail
                string mail = ((TextBox)row.FindControl("textBox2")).Text.ToString();

                //Mobile
                string mobile = ((TextBox)row.FindControl("textBox3")).Text.ToString();

                // Here you have all the edited row informations, you can do whatever you want with it
            }

        }
    }
```